# React-router v4 shared component with parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm using react-router v4 and I have a component that should appear both in '/' and '/view/:id'.

In the common component I can access location when the route is '/view/:id' however I wonder if there is a way I can access the 'id' parameter.

Here's the code I'm using and a quick [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/x2o9jmnv5z).

```
 <Router>
    <div>
      <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none", padding: 0 }}>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/view/a">a</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/view/b">b</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <hr />
      <Route
        path="/"
        render={ ({match}) => (
          <div>
            <div>
              <b>Common component</b>
              <p>{"Params " + JSON.stringify(match.params)}</p>
              <i>How to access params.id here?</i>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <Route
              path="/view/:id"
              render={({ match }) => <div>{"Params " + JSON.stringify(match.params)}</div>}
            />
          </div>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  </Router>
```

Comment: @user4418284 Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question:"How can I access the parameter **id** when the path is "/"?"

You cannot access a parameter which you do no pass.

In Link A and B you are passing a parameter in URL. `path="/view/:id"`  the `id` being the key and the value will be variable you pass in the URL.

when you access the root there are no parameters passed to it `path="/"`

Comment: The common component will also render when the path is "view/:id". Although I understand the question may be misleading so I've edited it.